# why defer tag differently in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am confused with tag name of `defer` in script tag. I created a demo react application where I inject a script .

here is my demo application  **(which is giving error which is expected output as I am using defer tag)**It is giving me error `x is not defined`.
In react application I used script tag like this

`<script defer language="JavaScript" src="./test.js"></script>`

**test.js**

```
window.x = (function () {
  console.log("jsss");
  function init() {
    console.log("--eeeee-");
  }
  return {
    init
  };
})();
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-shockley-zuchs?file=/public/index.html

I am injecting a script like this

so it is giving me error sometime `x is not defined` which is expected as I am using defer tag in script of `js will be excecuted after HTML parse`.

but same concept I used in **nextjs** which is react server side framework.

I used like this

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import React,{useEffect} from 'react';




export default function Home({a}) {
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("----");
         console.log(x.init());
    },[])
    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>My page title</title>
                <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width"/>
                <script defer language="JavaScript" src={`/js/test.js`}/>
            </Head>
        <div className="">
                <div className="jjjjjj">hello</div>
        </div>
    </>
    )
}
```

I am injecting a script with defer tag.but is not giving me error any time why ?? expected output it should give error at least once in hundred time .

Comment: I just checked out the code sandbox and there is no error for me.

Comment: @Gh05d refresh `result` window you will see error

Comment: I just refreshed the integrated browser several times, but I always see this text: Hello CodeSandbox
Test
Start editing to see some magic happen!